# Delete multiple, specific lines from text file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2019

I am working on a powershell script to edit a text file generated from registry.pol. The end goal is achieving CIS L1 benchmark. In order for CIS L1 to work in AWS EC2-image-builder as described in [this link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/cis-windows-ec2-image-builder/) the following sections need removed:

```
Computer
Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services
fPromptForPassword
DWORD:1

Computer
Software\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\PublicProfile
AllowLocalPolicyMerge
DWORD:0

Computer
Software\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\PublicProfile
AllowLocalIPsecPolicyMerge
DWORD:0
```

Here is my code so far to pipe everything *but* these 3 sections to output file:

```
Get-Content -Path C:\MS-L1.txt -Raw | where -notmatch {
  if( $_.StartsWith("Computer") ) {
    $section = select-string -pattern Computer -context 0,3
    if( ($section -like "fPromptForPassword") and ($section -like "AllowLocalPolicyMerge") and ($section -like "AllowLocalIPsecPolicyMerge") ){
    }
  } | Out-File c:\MS-L1.txt
```

I am trying to figure out how to select certain sections whose first line is "Computer" but not *all* the sections whose first line is "Computer", only if the lines following "computer" also match what needs removed:

1. check for "computer" in a line
2. store current line and next 3 lines as a section
3. check the section for the unique registry setting (i.e. fPromptForPassword)
4. repeat for section 2 (starting at "computer")
5. repeat for section 3 "                      "
6. Pipe the remaining(unselected) output to MS-L1.txt

I believe using -context to examine the 3 lines following "computer" is feasible but am not confident in the formatting of my nested if statement, thank you for any guidance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using `Get-Content -Raw` to read the input file in full anyway, it is more efficient to use a single [`-replace`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) operation:

```
(Get-Content -Raw C:\MS-L1.txt) -replace '(?m)^Computer\r?\n.+\r?\n(?:fPromptForPassword|AllowLocalPolicyMerge|AllowLocalIPsecPolicyMerge)\r?\n.+(?:\r?\n)?'
```

<sup>Note: If you know you're always dealing with CRLF newlines (Windows-style), you can use `\r\n` instead of `\r?\n`; if you're always dealing with LF newlines (Unix-style), `\n` will do.</sup>

For an explanation of the regex used above, including the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com  page](https://regex101.com/r/YWSeG3/1).

---

As for **what you tried**:

**Syntax problem**:

Your [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) (`where`) command mixes [*simplified syntax*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_simplified_syntax) with passing a *script block*, which isn't supported; in the abstract you have two choices:

- Simplified syntax: `... | where someProperty -notmatch $someRegex`

  - Note that implicitly operating on the input object *as a whole* instead of on one of its *properties* is - unfortunately - not supported as of PowerShell 7.2, but [GitHub issue #8357](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8357) proposes to fix that in the future. With this enhancement, you could then do something like `1..5 | Where -gt 2`, which currently fails.
- Script-block syntax: `... | where { $_.someProperty -notmatch $someRegex }`

**Conceptual problems**:

- Your command is designed to be *line-oriented* (though you'd have to remove the `-Raw` switch to actually send the input file's lines *one by one* through the pipeline), so you'd have keep track across multiple lines in your [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) script block in order to exclude *blocks* of lines from your input.
- While direct use of [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) with its `-NotMatch` switch offers *excluding* matching lines in principle, you cannot meaningfully combine this with the `-Context` parameter, because the additional lines captured as context are *not* subject to this exclusion.